# GET method returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, react-native

so im using GET method here and i want to get the id of the results here is my code :

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    CmdCart: [],
    id: ""
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://10.0.2.2:4000/getcmd", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(async(results) => {
      try {
        this.setState({
          CmdCart: results
        })
        console.log("CmdCart", this.state.CmdCart)
        this.setState({
          id: this.state.CmdCart._id
        })
        console.log("id", this.state.id)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })
}
```

but it return an undefined value of id , here is my log console :

[image]

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Looks like `results` is an array; try `this.state.CmdCart[0]._id`. Also, there's no reason for your last `then()` callback to be `async`

Comment: there's never any reason to mix `.then` with `async`

Comment: Phil , your answer only returns first id not all of them , how can i return them all ?